# Mysql Join query running with errors in result

Tags: java, mysql, inner-join

EDIT: [I have a mysql table for items in and items out  displayed as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/334Zs.png)

When I run the following query to display the number of items entered and items taken, I get the following result.

[Results after running the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh1oM.png)

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ii.item_in_nme 'Items In'
              , SUM(ii.item_in_quantity) 'Quantity In'
              , io.item_out_nme 'Items Taken'
              , SUM(item_out_quantity) 'Quantity Taken'
              , item_taken_by 'Taken By'
              , SUM(ii.item_in_quantity) - SUM(item_out_quantity) 'Available quantity' 
           FROM items_in ii 
           JOIN items_out io 
             ON io.item_out_nme = ii.item_in_nme 
          GROUP 
             BY ii.item_in_nme
              , io.item_out_nme
```

The Sugar quantity displays a strange figure.

Can you help me identify what am doing wrong

Comment: Why a `Java` tag? And please specify what is meant by 'strange figure'

Comment: In the image you have provided, there is no **item_out_quantity** column exists.

Comment: Just for fun, see how many examples there are out there combining DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query. ;-) (There are legitimate reasons why both might appear in the same query, but not many)

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query